# Can external object data be mocked?

Tags: externalobjects

We have a customer that has several large (many fields) external objects in their internal production environment. We need to do some development that will be very dependent on those object definitions but in separate development orgs.

I see that there is a separation of the "External Data Source" definition from the "External Object" definition. One of the "External Data Source" type options is "Salesforce Connect: Cross-Org".

Has anyone successfully setup custom objects (`__c`) in one org and exposed them in another org as external objects (`__x`) so code can be developed that is tightly coupled to the external object names?

Or any other suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: Does this github lib help? [SObjectFabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator) although I'm not sure I fully follow the question

Comment: @cropredy Perhaps, but was thinking of a mechanism where queries can be run rather than the queries having to be replaced by mocked responses.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Apex Connector](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_start.htm). I would recommend because then you have the freedom to create mocked responses manipulating the behavior as you wish (with no DML though).

The other option would be using https://www.mocky.io/ (or similar) or creating your own service on Heroku, for instance.

Comment: Keith specifically states that he doesn't want to mock responses!

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression he wanted due to the title.

Comment: Thanks Jeferson. I wasn't aware of the option of keeping it all in the org via the Apex Connector so that has some appeal...

Comment: @JefersonChaves Fair point :)